# How to print, on the eclipse console, an object of class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate, plsql

I have a `SELECT` query on an Oracle database that I want to run in two ways :

- Directly in SQLDeveloper
- In Eclipse with Hibernate, as a native SQL query.

And I want to make sure the Hibernate way works by comparing the results with the SQDeveloper way. 
And to do that, I need to print the results on the Eclipse console : this is when I get the error.

The query looks like this :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ... FROM ... AS b").addScalar("b", ClobType.INSTANCE);
```

So, it should return a list of `[]Clob`.

To print the result, I do this :

```
List l = query.list();

for (final Object row : l) {
  final Object[] columns = (Object[]) row;
  // use columns[0],  columns[1] etc
  System.out.println(((Clob) columns[0]).getSubString(0, 20));
}
```

I get the error at the following line : `final Object[] columns = (Object[]) row;`

It says : **com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24 cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;**

And indeed when I want to know the class of `l.get(0)` :

```
System.out.println(l.get(0).getClass());
```

It says : `class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24`

But normally, it should be `[]Object`.

So I cannot access `l.get(0)` because I do not know its class and how to deal with it.

I searched for that problem elsewhere but did not find relevant information.

And the final problem is that I can not compare my result with the SQLDeveloper way to make sure the Hibernate way works.

Thanks for helping.